# Does git provide a way to find by whom a branch or tag was created?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-tag

There are SOF questions about how to find a branch or tag creation time. But I am further bothered with "by whom" these things were created.

Does git store this meta-info and provide a means to query it at later time.

Comment: short answer: `Nope, it's not saved.`

Comment: The slightly longer answer is that: `a branch is just a pointer to a revision.... it can be crated/moved/detroyed at will at any time`. When you create branch , you are just setting up a _pointer_ to a revision with the name of the branch you decide to give it, but no more git objects are created.

Comment: how about a tag: the progit book quotes **"The tag object is very much like a commit object — it contains a tagger, a date, a message, and a pointer."** so the tagger does or does not refer to a person ???

Comment: not recording the creator of a **branch** could leave little or nothing to audit to find anyone messing up with the repo!!! bit wondered that why this choice was made.???

Comment: Branch names are local to one repository. Given that only I have access to my own repository, it doesn't matter what I do with the branch names. Now, something like GitHub might well want to add a "name update audit trail", but that's not part of Git itself.

Comment: @torek, tx.  given this scenario: if i am running my own repo which hosts public projects. Then I wish that the branch has some meta-data just like commits so users could know who the maintainer is (creator). Then how do I achieve this feature. Can Hooks solve this. (- don't think as there is no where to store this maintainer data)

Comment: Rather than some sort of hook, you could provide either your own separate database, or a (maybe private) ref name, along with some sort of REST and/or web interface to store metadata updates, however you like. For instance you could have `refs/samshers-metadata` or `refs/samshers-metadata/*` that you would use the point to objects you store (blobs, or commits with trees with blobs, or whatever you like). Compare with `git notes` for instance.

Comment: @torek, tx and sorry. Lost a bit.  if am getting it right: the implication is to store this data (meta-data of branch/tag) out of git repo??? and `refs/samshers-metadata` : are you referring to .git or a rest api.

Comment: One way is to store it out-of-repo (separate database). Another is to store it in-repo, in which case it *can* be copied by clone/fetch (as pull requests can be from GitHub). I expanded the in-repo method slightly above.

Answer (score 0):

An *annotated* tag is a reference of the form `refs/tags/name` that points to a Git object of type `tag`.  A `tag` *object* contains the `user.name` and `user.email` (or otherwise supplied name-and-email) of the person who created the tag, along with date-and-time stamps and optionally a message and PGP signature.  The tag object also contains the hash ID of the target of the tag, which otherwise would have been stored directly in `refs/tags/name`.  The target may be any existing object (blob, tree, commit, or previously-existing tag).

A *lightweight* tag points directly to some (non-tag) object and therefore has no additional metadata of its own.